# How do I return a list of all variables according to their counts?

Tags: r, count, duplicates, return

So I have a column for variables and a column for their counts.

```
vars <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
counts <- c(1,3,2,3,0)
```

I want to return a list/vector of

```
"a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "d" "d" "d"
```

Any tips?

Comment: What programming language do you have to use?

Comment: @MaxMartynov I use R!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rep`

```
rep(vars, times = counts)
#[1] "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "d" "d" "d"
```